# Is it possible to add group members to a group using Java Exchange service API for office 365 email?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am using Java API for exchange web services. Below is the code I have which is currently getting all of the group members from a group, but I wanted to know if I can add a member to the group within the code.

```
    ExchangeService service= instance.getEgrsEmailConnection();
    ExpandGroupResults myGroupMembers = service.expandGroup("testgroupone@usepa.onmicrosoft.com");
    myGroupMembers.getMembers();
```

This code gets a group based on that group's email address, but I can't think of a way to add a member. Any tips will be helpful, Thanks.

The api I am using is: ews-java-api-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

If testgroupone@usepa.onmicrosoft.com is a Distribution List (eg either a Universal Distribution Group UDG or Mail Enabled Universal Security Group) then no there are no EWS operations that allow you to modify the members of these type of groups. To do that you need to use either LDAP or the Exchange Management Shell. In EWS you an only modify Contact Groups which are Exchange Store objects that exist in a Mailbox or Public Folder.

It looks like you using Office365 so I would suggest using the Graph API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974478.aspx you can use the REST interface to easily manage groups from Java https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks, It was distribution list. Ill look into the Graph API, but for now I am trying to get the contact group working instead. I can add group members to the group, but a problem I am having is getting a list of members within the contact group(ContactGroup) using the api. I can't even see the members when I use the getMembers method unless I add an email address in that session. Although I can find the email addresses in the group using the class(ExpandGroupResults), but I needed to remove GroupMembers and I can't do any modifying using that class. Any ideas? I can post code.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using a contact group instead of a regular group, and found how to add and delete if anyone was having trouble like me:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(111);
    //Get all items in the Contacts folder
    FindItemsResults<Item> items = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);

    for(Item contactItem: items)
    {
        //If the item is a contactGroup then enter.
        if(contactItem instanceof ContactGroup)
        {
            PropertySet set = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            ContactGroup currentContactItem = ContactGroup.bind(service, contactItem.getId(), set);

            GroupMemberCollection members = currentContactItem.getMembers();
            Iterator<GroupMember> memberList = members.iterator();
            ArrayList<GroupMember> removePerson = new ArrayList<GroupMember>();
            ArrayList<GroupMember> addPerson = new ArrayList<GroupMember>();
            while(memberList.hasNext())
            {
                GroupMember current = memberList.next();

                removePerson.add(current);
                if(current.getAddressInformation().getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("test@gmail.com")) 
                {
                    addPerson.add(current); 
                }
            }

            for(GroupMember deletion: removePerson)
            {
                boolean happen = members.remove(deletion);
                if(happen)
                {
                    System.out.println("YESSS");
                }
            }
            for(GroupMember addition: addPerson)
            {
                members.add(addition);
            }
            if(removePerson.size() > 0 || addPerson.size() > 0)
            {
                currentContactItem.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
            }

        }
    }
```